# ubuntu 13.04 wifi lost connection - how to get it work again? (broadcom4313)

Tags: networking, wifi, broadcom

My problem is that I moved to a new flat where I at first couldn't find my home wlan network in the list, whereas others were shown (also, no one of my flatmates has problems with the network). so I tried to help myself by examining ubuntu-forums which lead me to the current state, where no network is detected at all, although my wifi is enabled. I don't know if it is of any use to know, but when opening an 'additional drivers' window, I am not able to enable broadcom corporation. I use ubuntu 13.04 on a thinkpad edge e335 and here some further infos, that might be of importance:

output of * lspci *

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

output of * rfkill list all *

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth

    Soft blocked: no

    Hard blocked: no

1: hci0: Bluetooth

    Soft blocked: no

    Hard blocked: no

3: phy1: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no

    Hard blocked: no
```

output of * lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network *

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0608]

        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-

        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR-

        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes

        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17

        Region 0: Memory at f0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

        Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms build-essential bcmwl-kernel-source
reboot
```

See:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/252499